# Pagination Styling Messed Up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to learn MVC and bootstrap. I am trying to display a table with page. I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0AnsVJbzMM).
 I am able to display, sorting, searching, and even able to paging. But my issue here is the styling. Somehow the styling is not as i desired. I am using [WebPagerReplacement](https://github.com/mdobie/WebGridPagerReplacement/blob/master/WebGridExtensions.cs)

Desired:
[image]

Actual:
[image]

```
<div>
        @grid.Table(
     tableStyle: "table table-striped table-hover",
     columns: grid.Columns(
         grid.Column(columnName: "FirstName", header: "First Name"),
         grid.Column(columnName: "LastName", header: "Last Name"),
         grid.Column(columnName: "EmailID", header: "Email"),
         grid.Column(columnName: "City", header: "City"),
         grid.Column(columnName: "Country", header: "Country")
            )
        )

        <div class="pagination pagination-small pagination-right">
            @grid.PagerList(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All)
        </div>

        @Html.Hidden("dir", grid.SortDirection)
        @Html.Hidden("col", grid.SortColumn)
    </div>
```

I know this is simple. But i am not sure why this happens and how to fix it. Please help me

Comment: How about using this: `@grid.PagerList(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, paginationStyle: "pagination pagination-small pagination-right")` instead of using those classes in `<div>`? Your paging of `PagerList` seem lack of styling there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of stuffing entire pagination classes in a single `<div>` element, you can try using `paginationStyle` parameter in `WebGridExtensions.PagerList` extension method:

```
<div>
    @grid.PagerList(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, 
                    paginationStyle: "pagination pagination-small pagination-right")
</div>
```

The reason behind parameter usage above is the presence of `TagBuilder.AddCssClass()` method which will add Bootstrap pagination classes for rendered `<ul>` element related to paging hyperlinks:

```
var ul = new TagBuilder("ul");
ul.AddCssClass(paginationStyle);
```

If you put those classes in outer `<div>` instead of `paginationStyle` parameter, the pagination classes are not applied in paging `<ul>` element, therefore all pagination texts and page numbers will rendered like standard hyperlinks.